# How to change a specific value in an ordered dictionary in python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish what I've outlined below.

I'm using an ordered dictionary to keep track of scores (values) for each player (keys).  The `for` loop repeats as many times as there are players.

My thought was to update the value of the key that is the same index as `x` in the for loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to execute it. Any suggestions are appreciated, it's entirely possible I'm approaching this the wrong way.

This is what I have so far :

```
numberOfPlayers = input("\nEnter number of players : ")
print("The number of players has been set to %s \n" % 
(numberOfPlayers))
numberOfPlayersInt = int(numberOfPlayers)
players = collections.OrderedDict()

for index in range(numberOfPlayersInt):
    teamName = input('Team/Player %i, enter a team name :' %(index))
    players[teamName] = 0

    for x in range(numberOfPlayersInt):
        print("Player %d, your question :" % (x + 1)) 
        answer = str(input("\nCorrect ? "))
        if answer.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            pass
            #some code here that updates the value for this player.
```

A dictionary with 3 entries, a - c, looks like this :

```
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)])
```

Comment: We can't see your dictionary. Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: Presumably your dictionary stores player keys as strings? If so you could have an array of player names, then in your for loop you should reference players[playerNames[x]]. Where players is your dictionary of players and scores

Comment: Correct, it stores them as strings.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So once you set players [teammame] =0 you would write playernames.append(teamname). Again where playernames is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your current dictionary and use that to build a replacement `OrderedDict` that has the new values.  By enumerating the items of our original `OrderedDict` we can get their index, then we can pass those vlaues to a function to determine their new values:

```
def new_value(index, key, value):
    print("Player %d, your question :" % (index + 1)) 
    answer = str(input("\nCorrect ? "))
    if answer.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        return value + 10
    else:
        return value

od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(['player1', 'player2', 'player3'], 0)

od = OrderedDict((k, new_value(i, k, v)) for i, (k, v) in enumerate(od.items()))
```

You could use a similar technique to modify the values in the existing dictionary:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(od.items()):
    od[k] = new_value(i, k, v)
```

Comment: I tried adding that and when it got to the for loop I got "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)".  I copied the function and changed the dictionary names to my own.  I added the for loop after creating the dictionary.  Was that wrong? And if so where should I put it? Thanks so much

Comment: @TheRedTopHat That was my fault, it should be `enumerate(od.items())` not `enumerate(od)`

Comment: Wow it worked!! Thanks so much you're an absolute lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to just update the current player's value following the name of the player as the key. I took your code and added some changes to be descriptive while making it a bit more pythonic in style (snake-case, etc.):

```
import collections

num_of_players = int(input("\nEnter number of players : "))
print("The number of players has been set to %s \n" % (num_of_players))

players = collections.OrderedDict()

POINTS_INCREASE = 5 # or any other update you want here

for index in range(num_of_players):
    team_name = raw_input('Team/Player %i, enter a name :' % (index))
    players[team_name] = 0

    print("Lets update player %d ..." % (index))
    answer = str(raw_input("\nCorrect (y, yes) ? "))
    if answer.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        players[team_name] += POINTS_INCREASE

print players
```